# C# Method that handles multiple different sql commands

Tags: c#, sql, command

I am trying to know if it is possible to implement a method that handles multiple sql commands with different number of parameters for the commands. For Example, I have a `stored procedure` that `INSERTS INTO table2 (userid, address) VALUES (@userid, @address)` which accepts a parameter `@userid`. While I have another `stored procedure` that `Inserts INTO table1 (userid, action, date) VALUES (@userid, @action, @date)`.

I am trying to implement a universal method so that I don't need to keep rewrite the code for each `SQLCommands`. What I have in mind is that I will store the lists of parameters and controls as a parameter to the method and the method will handle the rest as follows:

```
private void exeCommand(string cmdText, string[]param, string[]controls)
{
   using(con = new SQLConnection(connectionString))
   {
      using(SQLCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
      {
         cmd.CommandText = cmdText;
         cmd.CommandType = System.Data.Type.StoredProcedure;

         foreach(string parameter in param)
         {
            foreach(Control ctrl in controls)
            {
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter, ctrl.Text);
            }
         }

         con.Open();
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
   }

}
```

Is this the right way to do so?Or is there any solution to this? Thanks

Comment: signature should be: ...exeCommand(string cmdText, string[]param, Control[]controls). Also specify that parameter is an input param

Comment: Your approach looks good .. Keep it up :)

Comment: "Possible" and "advisable" are two different things. Speaking of, why are the `param` and `controls` arrays different? Shouldn't there be a 1:1 relation between an entry in `param` and an entry (at the same index?) of `controls`? If so, it might be better to have them combined somehow. Maybe in something like an `SqlParameter` class. Hey, that already exists... -- the way you use it now, you multiply `param` with `controls`.

Answer (score 0):

You create function like this:
1. Use this function to addparameters

```
 public void AddParameters(SqlParameter Field)
{
    Comm.Parameters.Add(Field);
}
```

2. Use this function to excute stored procedure

   ```
        public string Save(string SpName)
               {
   SqlConnection Conn = OpenConnection();  // connection open function you create this funciton

   String rv = string.Empty;
   try
   {
       Comm.Connection = Conn;
       Comm.CommandText = SpName;
       Comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       Comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
       rv = ("Successfully Saved.");
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       rv = ("Fails :" + ex.ToString());
   }
   finally
   {
       if (Conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
           Conn.Close();
   }
   return rv;
   }
   ```

Comment: Where does `Comm` come from? Why use `try..catch..finally` instead of `using`?